# Eval function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eval

Code:

```
 console.log(propertyName);
 console.log(eval(this.state.propertyName))
 console.log(this.state.DriverFirstName);
```

Output:

```
DriverFirstName
undefined
fsdfds
```

I want to acces to variable defined by string value(propertyName).
I have tried Eval function.
Why is my variable undefined, if i try to access it by eval function?

Comment: What are you trying to do? can you show what's inside `this.state`? if possible, delete the word `eval` and forget it exist

Comment: There are almost no good reasons to use `eval()`. Plus, we can't help because you don't show the definition of `this.state.properyName`.

Comment: `propertyName` is not the same as `this.state.propertyName`

Comment: I want to acces to variable defined by string value(propertyName)

Comment: @Bobek, can you do `console.log(this.state)` and paste the output in your question?

Comment: @chris there i get ouput of all my variables in this.state also with variable DriverFirstName which has value "fsdfds"

Comment: @Bobek please help me help you by doing what I am asking of you :)

Comment: @Chris I appreciate that you want to help me, but you dont need that. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is this:
`this.state[propertyName]`

This will access the state property which matches the value of the variable `propertyName`.

Given that `propertyName` value is `'DriverFirstName'`, it's the same as doing `this.state['DriverFirstName']` which is the same as doing `this.state.DriverFirstName`.